# the code that works in Xcode 6 doesn't work with Xcode 7

Tags: swift, xcode6, sprite-kit, xcode7

this is my first question here and apologize for bad English.

I was recently making a game application using Xcode 6.4 which worked perfectly in IOS devices. However, when I upload Xcode 7 Beta 4 to develop my app for IOS 9 there was a problem.

I was using this code in Xcode 6, which was restricting my hero to flip between -1.0 and 1.0 in X-axes, my hero could not flipping to -2.0 :

```
func flip() {
        isUpsideDown = !isUpsideDown

        var scale: CGFloat!
        if isUpsideDown {
            scale = -1.0
        } else {
            scale = 1.0
        }
        let translate = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: scale*(size.height + kMLGroundHeight), duration: 0.1)
        let flip = SKAction.scaleYTo(scale, duration: 0.1)

        runAction(translate)
        runAction(flip)
    }
```

But now in Xcode 7 this cod seems to not work. Firstly it seems alright but then hero starts to flip to -2.0, -3.0 and this goes on until the hero goes out of frame.

Also this is my game scene cod which worked perfectly on Xcode 6:

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if isGameOver {

            restart()

        } else if !isStarted {

            start()

        } else {

            hero.flip()

        }

    }
```

I am new to this things and would be appreciated if you answer my question.

Comment: What are the values of size.height and kMLGroundHeight? If their sum is greater than 1, the hero is going to move farther in the y direction than the (-1, 1) range you expect.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a breakpoint in the flip function and stepping through where it is getting changed to and looking at the trace...

Or one concentrated breakpoint strategy is to add a `didSet` to your `scale` property for when the value is set to be out of range.  Then look at the trace to see why things have gone wrong.

Modify `scale` to look like this.

```
var scale:CGFloat!{
    didSet{
        if scale < -1.0 || scale > 1.0{
            print("scale is out of bounds : \(scale)")
            print("stop here")//<< put breakpoint on this line
        }
    }
}
```

If you need help with using breakpoints look through [this](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode).